# Key 42 (USB HID codes)

Tags: keyboard, hid

Can anybody explain what a key with position 42 on AT-101 keyboard is? This key has Usage ID 50 (dec) in USB specification.

[image: IBM keybdtech]

On my AT-102 keyboard it looks like Backslash key, but Backslash key is located at position 29 here and has Usage ID 49.

[Hut1_12v2.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20180827225742/http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/Hut1_12v2.pdf) (page 54)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the region, in the UK it is a key that contains the ~ and the # (if a shift key is pressed).
In the UK the Enter's key shape is different and takes the space of position 29 and position 43.
In the document you linked to on page 54 the line with usage id 50 contains the explanation (Keyboard Non-US # and ~), and there is a reference to footnote 2 on page 59. 
[image: footnote 2:]

below is a 102 key layout

[image]

and here is a example from 2 keyboards, one for the US market and one for the UKmarket.

UK market:
[image]

US market:
[image]

However it appears that this key is used on the 102-key keyboard layout.

You can find more details and examples here:
https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-code/

Comment: Can someone point me to the source of the source of the key position code illustration? I can't find it in the PDF, I found similar illustrations on vt100.net, but not all of them. Also, the PDF menyions "Typical AT-101 Position" but I'd like to have a look at all available diagrams, etc.